# PDO exec error for int value

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to save a UNIX timestamp using PDO exec but I get an access violation:

> ```
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
> ```
>
> right syntax to use near '1300507025'

When I use a string, exec works as expected. What do I need to do to get this to work with integer values?

here is the statement

```
exec( "CREATE DATABASE $dbName" );
```

Comment: Please include the code that triggers this error.

Comment: Not an "access violation" by any stretch of the imagination...

Comment: Your database name can not start with a number.

Comment: @Jon: A direct quote from my error log: **access violation**: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1300507025'

Comment: @Jesse. I've been using numbers for years. Do you mean that PDO enforces this? MySQL allows it

Comment: Try adding backticks to the db name?

Comment: No, I didn't. I'll give that a shot. Why didn't I think of that?? :)

Comment: @Cambraca, that didn't work. Nice thought though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an astoundingly bad idea, but you are going to need to use backticks to create the database:

```
mysql> create database 123;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '123' at line 1
mysql> create database "123";
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"123"' at line 1
mysql> create database '123';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''123'' at line 1
mysql> create database `123`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| 123                |
...

mysql> select @@version;
+-----------+
| @@version |
+-----------+
| 5.0.77    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks Charles. I've already tried using backticks but that doesn't work. I'm going to just use an MD5 hash and be done with it. Thanks.

Comment: If backticks aren't working, then you're doing something wrong -- as I demonstrated above, they seem to work with pure-numeric database names.  Also, keep in mind that the restriction on automatic identification of identifiers is triggered when the identifier starts with a number.  md5 hashes can still start with a number.

Answer (score 0):

`exec( "CREATE DATABASE \'$dbName\'" );` just single quote the database name.

edit:

this only works if you have already:

```
SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';
```

otherwise use escaped back tick marks

Comment: Thanks Marlon. Here is the error: the right syntax to use near '\'1300509172\''

Comment: I'll probably just wind up use a string.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html check the error in there: mysql> CREATE TABLE "test" (col INT);
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax...
mysql> SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';
mysql> CREATE TABLE "test" (col INT);  
MYSQL wants ` back tickmarks...you could escape those or set the SQL mode above.